# How to tag friends via mobile web site, m.facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-tags

On the Facebook website it is possible tag friends on your status update—just type `@` followed by the first few letters of your friend’s name. The same holds good for any Facebook page you like. But how to do this on the mobile web application?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know their Profile ID. If you go to their profile page you will see it in the URL. Look for the part in the web address that contains the following:

```
id=
```

An example:

```
m.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XYZ
```

If they have a custom name, then go to `http://graph.facebook.com/username` replacing `username` with their custom name. It will return something like this:

```
{
  "id": "XYZ",
  "name": "Pobody Nerfect",
  "first_name": "Pobody",
  "last_name": "Nerfect",
  "username": "username",
  "gender": "asexual",
  "locale": "en_GB"
}
```

Remember the user profile ID (`XYZ` in the examples) and use the following to tag them via the mobile site:

```
@[XYZ:0]
```

You can replace the zero with the name you want to show up in the post.

Found via: [Tag Friends or Pages from Facebook Mobile Version!](http://www.websters7.com/Thread-how-to-tag-friends-or-pages-from-facebook-mobile-version)

Comment: No need to wiki. You can self-answer questions if you want.

Comment: Preferable if you don't link using URL shortener in future and summarise the page you're linking to

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you can type `@` and then part of your friend's name. Then a list of friends should appear, but it is a little buggy. Also, you can't remove the last name, like you can on the desktop website.